# What is the command to get ospatches and Network conf in HPUX-PARISC?

Tags: linux, hp-ux

Some examples in other systems

```
ospatches in HPUX-IA64 is "swlist -l fileset"
ospatches in Linux is "/sbin/ifconfig -a"
Network Configuration in Linux is "/sbin/ifconfig -a"
```

I want a equivalent ospatches and Network conf command for HPUX-PARISC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for patches on HP-UX PA-RISC 11.23:

`swlist -a patch_state *,c=patch`

or for lots of information about the installed patches:

`swlist -v patch_state *,c=patch`

**Update**

Actually swlist is in `/usr/sbin`

`/usr/sbin/swlist -a patch_state *,c=patch`

Comment: In my system it shows <br/><br/> $ swlist -a patch_state *,c=patch
sh: swlist:  not found.

Comment: ya more with /sbin/ifconfig -a in linux, something that shows all available eth0 and its info

Comment: I checked it, I guess this might do